# Size of database in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database

When using MongoDB's .stats() function to determine document size, are the values returned in  bytes. I would returned in Mo.Does anybody have any suggestion ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You add `1024*1024` to the parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the values are returned in bytes.
If you want to get result in kb pass 1024 and for mb pass(1024*1024) like this

```
db.collectionName.stats(1024) //for output in kb
```